# Eliminating Duplicate Entries from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Date       positions      price                   
2009-03-03       buy   3.156071
2009-12-10       buy   7.015357
2010-02-02       buy   6.995000
2010-03-04      sell   7.525357
2013-09-24       buy  17.467857
2013-10-08       buy  17.176428
2014-01-16       buy  19.794643
2014-01-28       buy  18.089285
2014-04-02      sell  19.376785
```

This is just a snippet of the DataFrame, but what I want to do is only have one row with "buy" in the positions column between two rows containing "sell" in the positions column. In other words, I want to eliminate the recurring buying signals AFTER the initial buying signal.

I want to eliminate the repeating buying signals after the first one has already happened. So, that would mean the expected output, given the first data frame would be:

```
Date       positions      price                 
2009-03-03       buy   3.156071
2010-03-04      sell   7.525357
2013-09-24       buy  17.467857
2014-04-02      sell  19.376785
```

Comment: Dont understand what you want, can you show example (expected output)?

Comment: I have just added the expected output to the problem description, but what I want to happen is I want to eliminate entries with buying signals if the entry prior contained a buying signal. More specifically, between each entry containing a selling signal, I want to keep the first buying signal and remove the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what you want the grouped `buy` to be.  I picked `sum` but maybe you want `mean`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2009-03-03',
  1: '2009-12-10',
  2: '2010-02-02',
  3: '2010-03-04',
  4: '2013-09-24',
  5: '2013-10-08',
  6: '2014-01-16',
  7: '2014-01-28',
  8: '2014-04-02'},
 'positions': {0: 'buy',
  1: 'buy',
  2: 'buy',
  3: 'sell',
  4: 'buy',
  5: 'buy',
  6: 'buy',
  7: 'buy',
  8: 'sell'},
 'price': {0: 3.156071,
  1: 7.015357000000001,
  2: 6.995,
  3: 7.5253570000000005,
  4: 17.467857000000002,
  5: 17.176428,
  6: 19.794643,
  7: 18.089285,
  8: 19.376785}})


df['g'] = (df['positions']=='sell').cumsum()
df = df.groupby(['g','positions']).sum().reset_index()
df.sort_values(by=['g','positions'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)

df[['positions','price']]
```

Output

```
   positions    price
0   buy     17.166428
2   sell    7.525357
1   buy     72.528213
3   sell    19.376785
```

Comment: I have a feeling OP wants `.first()` instead of `.sum()` and second note - don't repeat input dataframe definition in your answer - it's unnecessary long because of this.

Comment: Thank you Chris, however this was not the solution I was looking for. I should have included the expected output to start, but I have just added it now. Thank you for you help!

Comment: @Jason this answer fit your need if you follow the comment above from this wonderful person... and also chris, really nice answer.!

Comment: Thank you Gregorz & Adir, you were right!

Comment: Thanks @Chris, your solution has many new functions I was not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your help. I have checked my output, and the final code I decided to use is:

```
# Filter out multiple buying signals
df['g'] = (df['positions']=='sell').cumsum()
df = df.groupby(['g','positions']).first().reset_index()
df.sort_values(by=['g','positions'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified based on @Chris solution:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
position='sell'
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['positions']!=position:
        df_new=df_new.append(row)
        position=row['positions']
df_new
```

```
Date    positions   price
0   2009-03-03  buy 3.156071
3   2010-03-04  sell    7.525357
4   2013-09-24  buy 17.467857
8   2014-04-02  sell    19.376785
```